# Inline conditional between more than 2 values

Tags: python, if-statement

I need to do something like this:

```
if A
 function(a)
elif B
 function(b)
else
 function(c)
```

I found here simpler version:

```
function(a if A else c)
```

Is there version for `elif`? Something like:

```
function(a if A b elif B else c)
```

How should I write this (if this exists)? The code above doesn't look right.

Comment: Are you sure you need that? This is too abstract to tell, but I can see some pretty undecipherable one-liners coming out from here. Perhaps a dictionary?

Comment: what are A and B ? values or expressions ? can you share the real code ? you need to call the same function with different parameters or different functions with same parameter ?

Comment: Expressions. I'm calling function (method actually). With matsjoyce help my code looks like this: pytanie.add_pytanie_rodzaj('Białe' if licznik_wewnetrzny < 10 else 'Czerwone' if licznik_wewnetrzny < 18 else 'Musujące')

Comment: About question title, I see that python version is not important, but I would google for answers with "if" or "elif" phrase, not "inline conditional".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, no `elif`s. Just chain the `if`s:

```
function(a if A else b if B else c)
```

Which is equivalent to (as [precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) is left to right):

```
function(a if A else (b if B else c))
```

Obviously this could get complicated (and over the PEP8 80 char limit), E.G.:

```
move(N if direction == "N" else E if direction == "E" else S if direction == "S" else W)
```

In which case the longer form is better:

```
if direction == "N":
    move(N)
elif direction == "E":
    move(E)
elif direction == "S":
    move(S)
else:
    move(W)
```

Comment: Oh... So elif is going back into else if. Looking at in now, I can't understand why I didn't figure it out, it's so nice and simple. I like python because of this. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes. I think adding elif would have made the expression uglier, not nicer, so they left it out.